# What are the library that use C# 4.0 dynamic as an essential part of it?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic

What are the library that use C# 4.0 dynamic as an essential part of it?

Comment: The fullest potentials of `dynamic` are _evil_.

Comment: A bit vague here - Technically any library that is using dynamic could use it to its "fullest potential". What exactly do you want to know about dynamism?

Comment: @SLaks...may I ask why? I mean dynamism isn't considered evil in JavaScript, so why, in your opinion (and others), would you consider it "evil" in .NET?

Comment: IronPython.  Since it interacts with python, a dynamic language.  I'd say that's a pretty full use.  And the reason series is because C# is not a dynamic language.  It's a statically typed, compiled language.  Dynamics are only there to smooth the bumps when you have to.

Comment: @series0ne: I'll give some examples.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer: DLR and `dynamic` are not the same.

Answer (score 4):

The most powerful uses of `dynamic` are evil incarnate and should never be used near production code.

For example:

```
var sql = SqlBuilder.MyDatabase 
        * "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE UserName = " + userName;
User result = sql;
```

`dynamic` could be used to turn `userName` into a parameter and turn the last line into an `ExecuteReader()` call.

*Inspired by Jon Skeet*

---

Another example:

```
var _ = RestClient.Builder;
var endpoint = _.https/_.api.stackexchange.com/2.1/_.answers
var results = endpoint(sort: "activity", order: "desc", site: "stackoverflow");
// Returns https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow as dynamic JSON
```

The `_` is needed to allow arbitrary identifiers.
You could get rid of the `_` using expression trees:

```
var endpoint = RestClient.Build((https, api, answers) => 
       https/api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers
);
```

This uses parameter names to allow arbitrary identifiers.

Comment: +1 for the inspiration alone :P

Comment: To be fair, that's nicer syntax than some of the micro-ORMs I've seen...

Comment: Um....this 2 line code looks completely brain frazzling for starters! :-S

Comment: @DavidL: I added an even worse one